# Why did I get the birthdate in Oracle with an extra zero? How to change my sql?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I wrote the select sql statement in DB SOLO and I can get the result like `2015-09-09 10:48:35`, but when I use the java jdbc to get the result, it always returns `2015-09-09 10:48:35.0`. And when I try to parse it into date format, I get an error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-09-09 10:48:35.0"
```

How to change my sql? In mysql, I can format it like this:

```
select date_format(birthday,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') birthday from student
```

Comment: Oracle's string formatting of dates is something like:
select to_date(birthday, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') birthday from student

---- http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

Comment: `date_format()` is not a function supported by Oracle.  Are you sure you are not using MySQL?

Comment: In oracle its to_char and the extra zero are the milliseconds, i presume

Comment: @PeterM. `to_date()` does **not** "format" a date. It converts a character value _into_ a date. To _format_ a date you need [`to_char()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions216.htm#SQLRF06129)

Comment: How are you getting the date value from the `SELECT` into the variable that you are trying to parse?  It looks like you are selecting the date as a string and then telling Java to convert it back to a date.  But you shouldn't need to do that (and you shouldn't do it).  You should be getting the date value from the database right into a Java `Date` object.    Date format shouldn't enter into it.

Answer (score 1):

Use TO_CHAR

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(birthday, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL
```